# cant get selected date of rad date picker using jquery

Tags: jquery, telerik, asp.net-4.0, raddatepicker

I have the following definition of rad date picker:

```
 <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="calStartUsingDate"  runat="server" DateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy">
                            <ClientEvents OnDateSelected="calcConsump" />
                        </telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

I tried to get the selected date of it, but the following statment always returns null !!

```
 start = $find("<%=calStartUsingDate.ClientID %>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this outside of your OnDateSelected function:

```
var start = $find("<%=calStartUsingDate.ClientID %>").get_selectedDate();
```

OR if you are using it in the OnDateSelected function it would look something like...

```
function calcConsump(sender, args){
    var start = sender.get_selectedDate();
}
```

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/calendar-client-side-rad-datepicker.html